# Encode Emoji icons

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
myString = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sad" withString:@"\ue058"];
```

I have tried the baove sample which works fine, So i stored the same text inside my sqlite table with varchar data type.

But when i try to replace the same , i just get this "\ue058" but not the emoji icons.So how should i encode or decode to display the emoji icons in a proper way.

Otherwise do i need to store the emoji icons string in adiffrent data type?

Please let me know and thanks for nay help

Answer (score 0):

I tried with NSUSerDefaults like,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"\ue058" forKey:@"sad"];
```

and accessed using,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sad"];
```

It worked well.

It didn work with sqlite because you would have obtained the string as UTF8 string.

Comment: thanks for the reply ,So , i n what format i should obtain it from db

Comment: I think you should use UTF16.